# When would a frozenset be useful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, frozenset

What are some examples of when using a frozenset would be the best option?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`frozenset()` objects can be used as dictionary keys and as values **inside** of `set()` and `frozenset()` objects, where `set` objects cannot. `set()` values are mutable and not hashable, `frozenset()` values are immutable and are hashable.

They are to `set` objects what `tuple` objects are to `list` objects.

Demo:

```
>>> s = set([1, 2])
>>> fs = frozenset(s)
>>> adict = {}
>>> adict[s] = 42   # a set as key does not work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
>>> adict[fs] = 42  # a frozenset as key works
>>> s.add(s)        # a set as value in a set does not work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
>>> s.add(fs)       # a frozenset as value in a set works
```

Recent Python versions will optimize the use of a set literal:

```
if somevar in {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}:
```

by storing a `frozenset()` constant with the bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile("if somevar in {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}: pass", '<stdin>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (somevar) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               4 (frozenset({'foo', 'baz', 'bar'})) 
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in) 
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15 
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15) 
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               3 (None) 
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

because the set literal cannot be mutated *anyway*; this makes using sets to test against very efficient. A regular `set()` cannot be stored this way as that would allow you to mutate the constant stored with the byte object.

Comment: I have also begun to dip my toes in .compile(). This has further solidified my understanding of this function too, personal thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To compliment what Martijn said, I frequently use them for cache keys. For example, a memoize decorator that would key off `(args, frozenset(kwargs.items())`.

Answer (score 0):

I should add that unlike a tuple (which can also be used as a dict key or set member because it's hashable), a `frozenset` is **unordered**, making it handy for cases where you don't care about ordering the items.

[here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/f6imf3/what_is_the_proper_use_case_of_a_frozen_set_vs_a/) is a detailed example, see **dbramucci**'s post.